# Apache doesn't start when trying to force WWW. in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I'm trying to force WWW. in Apache's httpd.conf file, not .htaccess, to increase performance. However, when I paste these lines into the first line of httpd.conf, and restart the server, Apache says, "The requested operation failed!".

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Where did you read about this performance increase?

Comment: @Stijn The official Apache documentation.

Comment: It's a pretty minor performance increase, and you're probably going to have other rewrites that you'll want to be application-specific. As soon as you do that, you'll lose whatever negligible increase you'd have by putting it in the httpd.conf

Comment: OK, just wondering because it seems like a micro optimization to me and hiding a site's config in the global config seems dirty.

Comment: Huh. I will keep these in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to start rewriting without loading the modules. This sort of thing is generally better to configure in a VirtualHost at any rate, as you're mapping a rewrite for a certain site. 
The error you get basically just means you have a syntax error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  </IfModule>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I uncommented the rewrite module, and now the server starts, and WWW. is forced. However, I copied and pasted your code before uncommenting the module, and it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion!